# How implementarion code exist just including header file

Tags: c++, header, include

It's a theorical doubt.
Suppouse you have a little library with just two files: lib.h. the headers from lib.cpp, the implementation code.
By convention, in C++ we include the lib.h in lib.cpp, that is, the lib.h "doesn't know" about the "lib.cpp" existence.
So, to use our library in a program, suppouse: myprogram.cpp and myprogram.h, I have to include just the "lib.h"
So, how my program will load the implementation of headers? If the headers files "doesn't know" about the implementations files existence?

Comment: You also have to compile the library source code into binary form (i.e. an object file, or a static or shared library), and link the application code against it.  See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing).

Comment: The premise of your question is false. The implementation code **does not** necessarily exist just including header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you compile the implementation into a library and link your program to that library. So, unless the implementation code is actually in the header, or in a file included by the header and therefore also distributed, your assertion that "implementation code exist just including header file" is false.

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell the linker about the `lib` file for example `lib.lib` or `lib.so`

`.cpp` files will be compiled to objects files and then to `.lib` or `.so` files.
In the project with `myprogram.cpp` you have to inform linker about `.lib/.so` file from `lib.cpp`.